# Should I use Parse SDK in developing andorid app or is it going to be deprecated?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am learning android. In a video course I came across parse sdk. I am still confused about why should I use parse in my android application. Is there any other alternative for it?

Comment: Donot Learn it (Parse). It is going to end soon :)

Comment: **I am still confused about why should I use parse in my android application** who said to you, that you should use the parse in your app.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I said till now I was confused whether to learn it or not. But I am sure not to learn it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse is an open source framework to build and host your back-end. 
 But I'm not sure if you should use it any-more because parse is shutting down soon..

So I will suggest to raise question in Q/A of your video course, what's the alternative they can provide for learning purpose

Comment: I will surely raise question in my video course. The course is totally based on android app development with parse. And as I was not knowing about I started this course.

Comment: Cool!! or if you know back-end language so that you can create your own api's and server stuff i think you can actually skip parse part.. developers use it mostly for push notification but there are better alternatives for sending notifications.. Whatever is feasible for you..

Comment: That course was totally based on parse. So I just wrote a review about it and raised question in FAQ. I have left that course and started the next course I was going to do after the course using parse. And I will think about what you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With the increased use of mobile devices, it is common for applications to offer features such as backup storage, data sync, data sharing etc. Building stand alone applications that only function and save their data on the device they are installed on is at times not feasible. A backend is usually needed where data can be saved and manipulated for the app to provide the service it was intended for.

Building this requires time, a different skill set and other resources (e.g. servers, push notification services, etc). Fortunately, there are several platforms that provide ready-made customizable backends that you can integrate with your apps. These are known as ‘Backend as a Service’, or BaaS in short.

Parse is one of the more popular Backend as a Service platforms. The service offers three products in one package: Parse Core, Parse Push and Parse Analytics.

Parse Core generally handles the saving of data and social media integration.

Parse Push is used to send push notifications. It enables the developer to customize, schedule and send push notifications to either all registered users or a select group of users.

Parse Analytics enables you to track your app’s data. You can track usage data such as installations, active users, user retention, push notification open rate etc.

You can get more information from here https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Comment: But why should I use it if its going to end soon?

Comment: Nobody asked you to use it. Thank You

Comment: @NiraliAcharyan Yes, it is going to end but it should not stop you from using it right now. There is no learning curve with using parse, you are just making api calls for the data in the cloud(i.e parse). If you are still confused, use Firebase instead. It's a popular alternative to parse.

Comment: @Shrinil No don't take it wrongly. I read your answer. It was perfectly right         what you said. But a question arise in my mind that still is there any reason to use parse as it is going to end? I just wanted to know if you or anyone else can advice.

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I agree with you. But what I think is, it is better not to learn it rather than learning app development through Parse and if I develop any then again migrating it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using it. But why would you want to use it knowing it will end? You can use it for your demo or testing apps.

Comment: @ShinilMS Thank you. And I have left that course as it was totally based on app development with parse and started with the next one. I think there no need to learn parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Parse if you like. Parse Server has been made open-source and there are now more options for hosting a parse based application than ever (https://www.back4app.com/ and https://www.sashido.io/ are two examples, there are many more or you can host your own). Parse.com is shutting down but it seems like Parse Server is going strong. The open source parse server does not include all the features that parse.com had but if you are starting to learn based on one of these new options that will not matter to you.